# Quirky behavior with Firefox margin css

Tags: css, firefox, margins

Something strange is happening with a margin setting in Firefox, I have a div with an id "wrap" with a top margin of 20px, when a user is logged in a div appears above the wrap div with an id of user_nav I don't want any margin above this div, but Firefox is for some unknown reaslon propagating the top margin I have on the wrap div to the user_nav div above it, it isn't happening in any other browsers.

If I remove the top margin from the wrap div it is removed from both.

I can get rid of it by giving the user_nav div a negative top margin, but that messes up all the other browsers.

```
div#user_nav {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
}


div#wrap {
width: 980px;
margin: 20px auto 30px auto;
}
```

Any ideas about what is happening?

Thanks

Rob Fenwick

Comment: Can you put your code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: It would be very helpful to see your html as well. As @Adrift said jsFiddle it up!

Comment: I am not familier with jsFiddle so I hope this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/69aD9/ I don't have all the code just the html and css, but you can see the behavior in Firefox Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed quirky behaviour - and it appears to be one of the effects of this old bug related to clearing block elements (or one of its many, many duplicates):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451791

One way to get around it is getting rid of the `<div class="clear">` and using the overflow method of clearing instead (though that's not *always* possible, e.g. - obviously - if you have content inside the cleared element that will extend outside it):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

I.e., remove `<div class="clear">` from inside `user_nav_frame` and apply `overflow: hidden` (and `width: 100%`) to it in the CSS instead to clear the floats:

```
div#user_nav_frame {
    background-color: #0A4D84;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69aD9/2/

There are counter-hacks too, if this won't work out in your case. See the above bug report.